# How to join two partially overlapping strings without duplication?

Tags: string-manipulation

I have this list of strings; first string overlaps with the second string, and second string overlaps with the third string. I want to combine those into a single paragraph.

```
str = {"Raymond went for a walk in downtown and had so much fun being \
there. After 6 o'clock he had to return for supper.", 
   "After 6 o'clock he had to return for supper. Yet, despite all his \
willpower and best efforts, he could not get going back.", 
   "Yet, despite all his willpower and best efforts, he could not get \
going back. So he decided to stay."};
```

Expected output:
"Raymond went for a walk in downtown and had so much fun being there. 
After 6 o'clock he had to return for supper. Yet, despite all his 
willpower and best efforts, he could not get going back. So he 
decided to stay."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply Fold[] and SequenceAlignment[...,Method->"Local"]

```
Fold[StringJoin[SequenceAlignment[#1, #2, Method -> "Local"]] &, str]
```

Output:

"Raymond went for a walk in downtown and had so much fun being there. 
After 6 o'clock he had to return for supper. Yet, despite all his 
willpower and best efforts, he could not get going back. So he 
decided to stay."

**Should you encounter a situation where the above does not work with your text...**

...Here is a custom solution:

```
MWhatToJoin[s1_, s2_] := Module[{posoverlap, pos1, pos2},
  posoverlap = LongestCommonSubsequencePositions[s1, s2];
  If[SameQ[posoverlap, {}], Return[{s1, s2}]];
  If[And[posoverlap[[1, 2]] == StringLength[s1], 
   posoverlap[[2, 1]] == 1], 
   Return[{s1, StringTake[s2, {posoverlap[[2, 2]] + 1, -1}]}]];
  If[And[posoverlap[[2, 2]] == StringLength[s2], 
   posoverlap[[1, 1]] == 1], 
   Return[{s2, StringTake[s1, {posoverlap[[1, 2]] + 1, -1}]}]];
  Return[{s1, s2}]
  ]
MJoinTextWithoutOverlap[s1_, s2_, separator_ : ""] := 
 Module[{ls1, ls2},
  {ls1, ls2} = MWhatToJoin[s1, s2];
  Return[StringJoin[ls1, separator, ls2]]
  ]
```

For overlap instances in MWhatToJoin[], consider replacing the functions in Return[...] with SequenceAlignment[...,Method->"Local"].